# Newton's Second Law And Horse Racing

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I'm a big racing fan and decided that I'd like to develop a better understanding of how weight impacts a horses performance.  I did some searching on the internet and came across this article:

[The Impact of Weight on the Performance of a Race Horse](http://www.goto4winds.com/horse/weighthorse2.html)

It seemed like the perfect fit, unfortunately when it came explaining how they got to the numbers they came up a little short.   Here is an excerpt from the article:

[image]

I was hoping someone could actually walk me through how the article is coming up with its numbers.

Comment: In the first approach they are just solving the differential equation $m\ddot{x}=f-k\dot{x}$ where $f$ is the force the horse exerts and $k$ is the linear drag coefficient (see [Stokes' drag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)#Very_low_Reynolds_numbers:_Stokes.27_drag)).

Comment: @lemon Thanks for the comment but would it be possible to you break this down a bit more for me using an example from the article. I'm out of my depth.  Many thanks and hope to return the favor sometime.

Comment: Regarding @lemon comment, Mutuelinvestor, this is as basic as we can get, as physics learners are language majorly consists of differential equations and newtonian mechanics, i recommemd you to read how to apply newtons laws to problems in mechanics and fprm basic force equation, this is the logical part, further is just mathematical analysis which you may learn under basic ordimary differential calculus